# Drop down menu's python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I have started a program to display my school time table this is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master2 = Tk()
var = StringVar(master)
var2 = StringVar(master2)
var.set("Day") 
var2.set("Week")

option = OptionMenu(master, var, "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")
option2 = OptionMenu(master2, var, "A", "B")
option.pack()
option2.pack()

Week = var2.get()
Day = var.get()
def ok():
    if Day == "Monday" and Week == "A":
        print("You have: \n P.S.E with Mrs Smith \n W.B.Q with Mrs Smith \n Science with Mr Martin \n Media wirh Mr Kelleher \n English with Mrs Jenkins (of mice and men)")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Tuesday" and Week == "A":
        print("You have: \n R.M with Mr Arnold/Mr Heywood \n English with Mrs Jenkins \n I.C.T with Mr Davies \n Maths with Mr Tucker \n I.T programing with Mr Arnold ")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Wednesday" and Week == "A":
        print("You have: \n English with Mrs Jenkins \n Science with Mr Martin \n Re with Mr Davies \n Media with Mr Kelleher \n R.M with Mr Arnold/Mr Heywood ")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Thursday" and Week == "A":
        print("You have: \n Games With Mr Davies \n I.C.T with Mr Davies \n I.T programing with Mr Arnold \n Science with Mr Martin \n Maths with Mr Tucker")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Friday" and Week == "A":
        print("You have: \n Maths with Mr Tucker \n English with Mrs Jenkins \n Media with Mr Kelleher \n I.T programing with Mr Arnold \n Science with Dr Burton")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Monday" and Week == "B":
        print("You have: \n Science with Dr Burton \n Re with Mr Davies \n Welsh with Mr Kedward \n English with Mrs Jenkins (of mice and men) \n Media with Mr Kelleher")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Tuesday" and Week == "B":
        print("You have: \n Maths with Mr Tucker \n R.M with Mr Arnold/Mr Heywood \n I.T programing with Mr Arnold \n I.C.T with Mr Davies \n Science with Dr Burton")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Wednesday" and Week == "B":
        print("You have: \n R.M with Mr Arnold/Mr Heywood \n Media with Mr Kelleher \n English with Mrs Jenkins \n Science with Miss Fair \n I.C.T with Mr Davies")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Thursday" and Week == "B":
        print("You have: \n Games With Mr Davies \n I.C.T with Mr Davies \n I.T programing with Mr Arnold \n Maths with Mr Tucker \n Science with Miss fair")
        input("Press enter to close")
    if Day == "Friday" and Week == "B":
        print("You have: \n Welsh with Mr Kedward \n Science with Miss Fair \n English With Mrs Jenkins \n Maths with Mr Tucker an R.M with Mr Arnold/Mr Heywood")
        input("Press enter to close")
    else:
        print("Error invalid choice")
        input("Press enter to close")


button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button2 = Button(master2, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()
button2.pack()
mainloop()
```

I am wondering how can I display the two options in the same Tkinter window also it does not set the value to the correct ones e.g: Day does not = Monday and Week does not = A instead they = "day week" and I am wondering how to fix this thanks. I am new too tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's three things here to address. I'll do them in the order I found them

#### Multiple instances of Tk

```
master = Tk()
master2 = Tk() # DON'T DO THIS
```

Never have two instances of `Tk` running at once. If you need a second window, use `tkinter.Toplevel`. You don't need a second window for this, however, so let's move on.

#### Change everything to be inherited by `master`

That includes `var2`, `option2`, and `button2`. In fact since we're dropping `master2` completely, just delete `button2`.

#### Make your `StringVar` update when the button is pressed

This is why your function isn't receiving the right info. You only assign `Day` and `Week` to `var.get()` and `var2.get()` once, and you do so right after you create the `OptionMenu`s when they're still on their default values. When you change the `OptionMenu` item, `Day` and `Week` never actually change. Instead do something like:

```
def ok():
    global var, var2
    Day = var.get()
    Week = var2.get()
    if Day == ...
    ...
```

#### Afterword

By the way, your `mainloop` call should be `master.mainloop()`. You always run `mainloop` from your instance of `Tk`, which is part of the reason why you shouldn't have more than one instance! There's also a good deal of inconsistency in variable naming schemes, to which I'll refer you to [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) since it's a bit outside of the scope of this answer. Just know that things like `var` for a variable name are vague and terrible, and `Day` and `Week` should be classes if they're capitalized like that. I'd also STRONGLY recommend removing your "Press Enter to Continue" lines. You don't need them. In fact remove your console interaction from the user: make a `Toplevel` and write to a `Label` on it.

All in all though, good work! This is one of the most correct beginning forays into Tkinter I've seen in a long time.